# Safe mode or not in C#?

Tags: winapi, c#

Доброго времени суток! 
 Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста, как проверить запущен ли комп. в нормальном режиме или в безопасном с помощью .Net? или winAPI

Заранее очень благодарен! Успехов всем!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SystemInformation.BootMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.bootmode.aspx)